# Cannot compile d3d12 simple app on MSVC C++

Tags: c++, directx

https://github.com/rdunnington/d3d12-hello-triangle

I found this example and decided to compile it in C/C++ project in visual studio, created new project, imported directx 12 sdk with Nuget and Ctrl+C/Ctrl+V main.c from this project.
And 80% of d3d12 calls and identifiers are undefined. Why?
How to build it properly?

Comment: What project template did you start from exactly?  Can you provide some example error output? What version of MSVC are you using?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the code sample you found is using "C" and not "C++". It's also building as "MBCS" rather than "UNICODE".

If you name the source file 'main.c' in Visual C++ and set the *Project Properties* Advanced -> Character Set to "Use Multi-Byte Character Set" it compiles as "C". You then have to add `d3dcompiler.lib`, `d3d12.lib`, `dxguid.lib`, and `dxgi.lib` to the Linker Additional Dependencies, then it will link assuming you have a "Windows Project" instead of a "Console Project".

That said, it's not a very good sample to start with unless you really want to use "C". All the Developer Education around DirectX 12 including samples, helper libraries, and docs assume you are using C++.

> I'd recommend instead you take a look at the official [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectX-Graphics-Samples) samples, and the [DirectX Tool Kit for DX12](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK12/wiki/Getting-Started) tutorials. There's also some basic DirectX12 samples [here](https://github.com/microsoft/Xbox-ATG-Samples/tree/main/PCSamples/IntroGraphics).